# Cannot purge nvidia-304 - DKMS issue returns a removal error

Tags: apt, nvidia

```
sudo  apt-get purge nvidia-304  
Reading package lists... Done  
Building dependency tree         
Reading state information... Done  
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  kde-l10n-engb screen-resolution-extra  
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.  
The following packages will be REMOVED:  
  nvidia-304*  
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.  
1 not fully installed or removed.    
After this operation, 172 MB disk space will be freed.  
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y  
(Reading database ... 274272 files and directories currently installed.)  
Removing nvidia-304 (304.125-0ubuntu1~xedgers14.10.1) ...  
Removing all DKMS Modules  
Error! There are no instances of module: nvidia-304  
304.125 located in the DKMS tree.  
Done.  
  File "/usr/bin/quirks-handler", line 54  
    pass  
       ^  
IndentationError: expected an indented block  
dpkg: error processing package nvidia-304 (--purge):  
 subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 1  
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.19-10ubuntu2.2) ...  
Errors were encountered while processing:  
 nvidia-304  
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I treed everything to get this error out but I can't do anything. Can someone help?
this happened after installing nvidia driver and now it's acting up.
i read many post that had the same problem and were solved but their ways didn't work with my ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this, and enter from the terminal:

```
  sudo apt-get install --reinstall dkms
  sudo apt-get -f install
  sudo apt-get install aptitude
  sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get upgrade
  sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
  sudo aptitude
```

and it might work fine this way.

Comment: I don't know why the negative vote. This answer set me on the right path with the ```sudo apt-get install --reinstall dkms```.

Answer (score 0):

Try a reinstall of `nvidia-304` first (`sudo apt-get install --reinstall nvidia-304`), then purge it afterwards.  I think this is caused by the DKMS module being missing so it couldn't remove fully, causing the error.

Comment: If this still does not work try: ```sudo apt-get install --reinstall dkms```.

Answer (score 0):

I tried Thomas W's suggestion but that didn't work because apt-get keeps failing with the same error about the module.

I found a to this question on another site: http://iswwwup.com/t/eb23b280a9f5/apt-cannot-purge-nvidia-304-dkms-issue-returns-a-removal-error.html which helped me out.

I ran `sudo apt-get -f install`, then ran the `sudo apt-get remove --purge nvidia-*` that was suggested but I had to run it twice. The first removed all the dependencies of nvidia-304 and the second time removed the module itself. Then I could continue with the dist-upgrade that I was doing.